# Select key value javascript param comment

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to make it so the user doesn't have to type in a value only select. For better understand this is what I mean.
[image: example]

But when I try running it is get this

```js
Promise { 'Isekai' }
{ error: true, error_message: 'This genre does not exist.' }
```

index.d.ts file:

```
interface fetchAnimeByGenre {
    animeTitle: string,
        animeId: string,
        animeImg: string,
        animeSeason: string,
        score: number
}
function fetchAnimeByGenre(genre:'Action' | 'Adventure' | 'Anti-Hero' | 'CGDCT' | 'College'): Array<fetchAnimeByGenre>;
```

```js
const GENRES = [
    'Action', 'Adventure', 'Anti-Hero', 'CGDCT',.....];
        if (!genre) {
            return {
                error: true,
                error_message: "No genre provided"
            }
        };
var list = []
        if (genre.toLowerCase() === "anti-hero") {
            genre = "Anti-Hero"
        } else if (genre.toLowerCase() === "cgdct") {
            genre = "CGDCT"
        } else {
            genre = firstLetterToUpperCase(genre);
        }

if (!GENRES.includes(genre)) {
    return {
        error: true,
        error_message: "This genre does not exist."
    }
};
        const res = await axios.request({
            url: animixBase + "api/search",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "User-Agent": USER_AGENT
            },
            data: new URLSearchParams({ genre, minstr: 99999999, orderby: "popular" })
        });

        res.data.result.map((anime) => {
            list.push({
                animeTitle: anime.title,
                animeId: anime.url.split("/v1/")[1],
                animeImg: anime.picture,
                animeSeason: anime.infotext,
                score: anime.score / 100
            })
        });

        return list;
```

Is there any way I can fix this? (side note: I am fairly new to this d.ts stuff so)

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example.  There's not enough code here to provide useful help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MattMorgan I apologize for the lack of detail, will this help get a better understanding?

Comment: It's not really enough code.  What is `GENRES`?  Why is there a promise involved?  This isn't a Typescript error, from what I can see, but who knows... Ideally you would post a complete enough example that someone could reproduce your issue.  It's the best way to get good-quality answers.

Comment: @MattMorgan mybad, GENRES is an array ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Anti-Hero', 'CGDCT', 'College', 'Comedy', 'Drama']